# number guessing python tkinter validation

Tags: python, validation, user-interface, tkinter

previous issue was resolved thanks to you guys can anyone also help me with the validation like if a person `clicks` check with empty field it prints a message in `entry2` like "Field cannot be empty" .Adding code for reference .

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title('Number Guessing Game E-project')
root.geometry('500x500')

label1 = Label(root, text= "WELCOME TO NUMBER GUESSING GAME",fg='Maroon',font= ('bold',17))
label2 = Label(root, text= "Enter your guess between 0-999:",font=('Italics',15), fg='Maroon')

label1.grid(row=1 , column=0  ,ipadx=20,pady=10)
label2.grid(row=4 , column=0 ,ipadx=10,pady=10)

player1 = StringVar(root,value="Generate A Random Number First")

entry1 = Entry(root,textvariable=player1,width=30,bd=4)
entry2 = Entry(root,width=30,bd=4)
entry1.grid(row =12 , column= 0 ,ipadx=10,pady=10)
entry2.grid(row =13, column= 0 ,ipadx=10,pady=10)

attempts = 10

chances = StringVar()
chances.set("10 Attempts Remaining")
label4 = Label(root,textvariable=chances,font='Italics')
label4.grid(row=7,column=0 ,ipadx=10,pady=10)

def clear_the_screen():
    entry1.delete(0,END)

def random_num_generate():
    global random_number , user_guess
    random_number = random.randint(0,999)
    clear_the_screen()

def player_input():
    try:
        user_guess = int(entry1.get())
        winning_logic(random_number,user_guess)
    except ValueError:
        entry2.insert(0,"Enter integers only!")
        result3 = 'Enter integers only!'
        entry2.delete(0, END)
        entry2.insert(0, result3)
        chances.set(f'{attempts} attempts remaining')
        clear_the_screen()


def winning_logic(random_no,player_guess):
    global attempts
    global chances
    attempts -= 1

    if attempts < 1:
        a = (f'You are out of attempts \n Try again')
        showinfo("Sorry", a)
        root.destroy()

    elif player_guess == random_no:
        result1 = 'Bravo! Success!'
        entry2.delete(0, END)
        entry2.insert(0,result1)
        chances.set(f'You Win!')
        win = (f'Congrats! You have guessed the correct number !')
        showinfo(f'Number Guessing Game', win)
        response = askquestion('Number Guessing Game', 'Did you like the game?')
        if response == 'yes':
            showinfo('Number Guessing Game', "That's Great!!")
        else:
            showinfo('Number Guessing Game',"So Sad!")
        root.destroy()

    elif player_guess < random_no and player_guess < 1000:
        result2 = 'Guess Higher!'
        entry2.delete(0,END)
        entry2.insert(0, result2)
        chances.set(f'Wrong! {attempts} attempts remaining')
        clear_the_screen()

    elif player_guess > random_no and player_guess < 1000:
        result3 = 'Guess Lower!'
        entry2.delete(0,END)
        entry2.insert(0, result3)
        chances.set(f'Wrong! {attempts} attempts remaining')
        clear_the_screen()

    elif player_guess > 999:
        result3 = 'Invalid Number!'
        entry2.delete(0, END)
        entry2.insert(0, result3)
        chances.set(f'Invalid Number! {attempts} attempts remaining')
        clear_the_screen()



button1 = Button(root, text='Generate Random No',fg='white',bg='brown',command=random_num_generate)
button1.grid(row=9, column=0,ipadx=20,pady=8)

button2 = Button(root, text='Clear',fg='white',bg='brown',command=clear_the_screen)
button2.grid(row=18, column=0,ipadx=73,pady=10)

button3 = Button(root, text='Check',fg='white',bg='brown',command=player_input)
button3.grid(row=20, column=0,ipadx=70,pady=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the input is empty in the `except` block inside `player_input()`:

```
def player_input():
    user_guess = entry1.get()
    try:
        user_guess = int(user_guess)
        winning_logic(random_number, user_guess)
    except ValueError:
        if user_guess == '':
            result3 = 'Field cannot be empty!'
        else:
            result3 = 'Enter integer only!'
        entry2.delete(0, END)
        entry2.insert(0, result3)
        chances.set(f'{attempts} attempts remaining')
        clear_the_screen()
```